Total cart Weight how to show order summary in magento 2.4.6
How can We achieve this?

We get total weight of products of cart in Magento 2 by \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart class
With objectManager
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

$weight = 0;
foreach($items as $item) {
   $weight += ($item->getWeight() * $item->getQty()) ;        
}

echo $weight;

With Factory Method
  protected $_cart;

  public function __construct(
  ...
  \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cartModel,
  ...
 ) {
    ...
    $this->_cart = $cartModel;
    ...
  }

  public function getTotalWeight()
  {
      $items = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

     $weight = 0;
     foreach($items as $item) {
        $weight += ($item->getWeight() * $item->getQty()) ;        
     }

   return $weight;
  }

